# c# client (windows) - server (linux debian) solution

Tags: c#, windows, linux

I need help with small app I am working on.
Its small client collecting some data from user and I need to sent them to server and receive data from server... Last time I made it: client in c# was getting data from server through webserver PHP...(sending POST request via c# and parsing output page) It will be beter to have TCP/IP connection...

Whats the best and easy solution to do that? I have skills in php, c# (not c++)
Does MONO support all c# socked functions? Is it possible to run MONO on linux debian server without graphical interface.. (bash only)?

I need to: send/receive data and authenticate user...

thx for help

Comment: IIRC, PHP supports [non-HTTP sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) too. You just wouldn't host the app in a web server (or maybe you could, not sure of the semantics of Apache).

Comment: I am sure you have thought this through Marek, but before you go down this route, are you sure going direct through TCP/IP and sockets is the way to go. You will have to reinvent a lot of what you get for free out of the webserver. Just playing devils advocate.